# How to print a dataframe which is read from a csv file into dictionary format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, ordereddictionary

I turned the data in a csv file into a dataframe by using Pandas then proceeded to print the dataframe into dictionary format by using Ordereddict.

However, the index numbers for each row are missing when I did it, is that anyway to retain the index number or anyway to achieve the same result with index numbers?

And I am not entirely sure the part with zip() and tolist(), can anyone explain their usages?

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
import collections

df = pd.read_csv('for_testing.csv')


for i, row in df.iterrows():
  d = OrderedDict(zip(row.index.tolist(), row.tolist()))
  print(d)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('First Name', 'Kate'), ('Last Name', 'Rose'), ('Occupation', 'Teacher'), ('Age', 24), ('Number', 87)])
OrderedDict([('First Name', 'James'), ('Last Name', 'Smith'), ('Occupation', 'Cook'), ('Age', 35), ('Number', 487)])
OrderedDict([('First Name', 'Nick'), ('Last Name', 'Carter'), ('Occupation', 'Writer'), ('Age', 44), ('Number', 896)])
OrderedDict([('First Name', 'Ray'), ('Last Name', 'Johnson'), ('Occupation', 'Designer'), ('Age', 34), ('Number', 412)])
OrderedDict([('First Name', 'Jay'), ('Last Name', 'Law'), ('Occupation', 'Unemployed'), ('Age', 25), ('Number', 123)])
```

I would like the Output to be like this:

```
1. OrderedDict([('First Name', 'Kate'), ('Last Name', 'Rose'), ('Occupation', 'Teacher'), ('Age', 24), ('Number', 87)])
2. OrderedDict([('First Name', 'James'), ('Last Name', 'Smith'), ('Occupation', 'Cook'), ('Age', 35), ('Number', 487)])
3. OrderedDict([('First Name', 'Nick'), ('Last Name', 'Carter'), ('Occupation', 'Writer'), ('Age', 44), ('Number', 896)])
4. OrderedDict([('First Name', 'Ray'), ('Last Name', 'Johnson'), ('Occupation', 'Designer'), ('Age', 34), ('Number', 412)])
5. OrderedDict([('First Name', 'Jay'), ('Last Name', 'Law'), ('Occupation', 'Unemployed'), ('Age', 25), ('Number', 123)])
```

Edit:
I noticed a problem, when I try to make the print triggered by an user input, it only displays the last row of the ordereddict dataframe instead of the whole ordereddict dataframe:

New code:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
import collections

df = pd.read_csv('for_testing.csv')

def main():
  choice = input("type sth ")
  
  if choice == '1':
      for i, row in df.iterrows():
        d = OrderedDict(zip(row.index.tolist(), row.tolist()))
      print(d)


main()
```

New Output:

```
type sth 1
OrderedDict([('First Name', 'Jay'), ('Last Name', 'Law'), ('Occupation', 'Unemployed'), ('Age', 25), ('Number', 123)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting your dictionary each time you define it in your loop. You can start by defining an empty dictionary outside of your loop, then assigning values to it in your loop. With `OrderedDict`, it should keep the items in the order you assign them:

```
d = OrderedDict()
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    d[i] = list(zip(row.index.tolist(), row.tolist()))
print(d)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, when I run this, I got: ``` OrderedDict([(0, <zip object at 0x7f16e2d83a40>), (1, <zip object at 0x7f16e1097ec0>), (2, <zip object at 0x7f16e1097cc0>), (3, <zip object at 0x7f16e10ab340>), (4, <zip object at 0x7f16e10ab200>)]) ```

Comment: @PypypieYum try putting `list` around the `zip` command. See my updated answer. Sorry, wasn't able to test this before posting.

Comment: Really appreciated! I noticed that the items are now embed into one OrderedDict(), but I would like them to list separately. Also, do you know why when I try to make it triggered by input, it will only list the last Ordereddict row instead of the whole dataframe?